# Found Unit but required Int in Scala. Simple code

Tags: scala, recursion, type-mismatch

Below is my code. Could someone explain to me what the problem is and how can I resolve it?

```
def max(list: List[Int]): Int =
if (list.isEmpty) throw java.util.NoSuchElementException()
else checkIfAnElementHigherThenOthers(list.head, list.tail)

@tailrec
def checkIfAnElementHigherThenOthers(accum: Int, list: List[Int]): Int =
if (accum < list.head) checkIfAnElementHigherThenOthers(list.head, list.tail)
else checkIfAnElementHigherThenOthers(accum, list.tail)
```

Comment: I don't see a base case.

Comment: Explain the problem your code is trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

`if (list.isEmpty) throw java.util.NoSuchElementException()`

this statement returns `Unit`, but function is declared to return `Int`, so the compiler complains. Removing `else` following it, should fix it.

(By "it") I mean the compilation error ... your function logic is still wrong :) (hint: your `checkIf...` function never returns, there is no case when it would not end up calling itself (or erroring out)).

Comment: Uhm probably the problem is related with the lack of `new`. Indeed, throw new Exception return Nothing not Unit that is quite different. `Nothing` is a subtype of all possible type (a bottom type). So I can assign an Exception to an Int ([scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nA3uckoWQ7avNChyrPcCKw)).